# Can't import Python module I just installed

Tags: python, module, pyqt5, python-import

I just installed PyQt5 using pip3.  When I try and import it, this doesn't throw any errors:

`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *`

However, when I try and actually access the library:

`app = QApplication(sys.argv)`

I get the "Undefined Variable" error on `QApplication`.

I've also tried importing like this:

`from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication`

which gives me the `"No Name QApplication in Module"` error.

This is frustrating me to no end, since I literally just installed the library, AND when I type in the import commands my IDE gives me predictive text, showing that the library is being detected.

Comment: How have you install it?

Comment: ```pip3 install PyQt5```, and I confirmed that it is installed

Comment: Possible answered in this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726580/no-name-qapplication-in-module-pyqt5-qtwidgets-error-in-pylint).

Comment: Thanks @c_sagan, that worked!