# Undefined variable 'QApplication' & Undefined variable 'QDialog'

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pyqt5, pylint, qapplication

My problem is after installing Python and PyQt5 in vs code, when I run the code he show me this problem:

[image]

```
Undefined variable 'QApplication'
Undefined variable 'QDialog'
```

But I found a solution here [No name 'QApplication' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' error in Pylint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726580/no-name-qapplication-in-module-pyqt5-qtwidgets-error-in-pylint) which is by adding `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5"]` in settings.json.

[image]

( I also try to put a comma at the last line `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--extension-pkg-whitelist=PyQt5,"]` but it doesn't work)

It solves the first problem and the code is working in a window, but it also create another big problem:

[image]

What should I do to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the warning here comes from pylint, and it does not affect the execution of the code, we can turn off this warning by adding the following settings in "`settings.json`":

> ```
> "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
>     "----extension-pkg-whitelist=1xml"
>   ],
> ```

Result:

[image]

Update:

You could use the following settings to turn off specific ("[undefined-variable](https://github.com/janjur/readable-pylint-messages/blob/master/README.md#undefined-variable)") pylint information:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
      "--disable=E0602"
    ]
```

It is recommended that you modify the code first (there is no code error, the code can be executed), and then turn off such warnings.

Comment: Hi thank you for your help, it turned off the warnings but also it turned off the errors, is there is a way to turn off the warnings only ?

Comment: @Hamid MM  -I updated my answer and you can refer to it.