# I can import PySide2.QtWidgets and use QApplication, but can not from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication

Tags: python, import, pyside2

I can import PySide2.QtWidgets and use QApplication, but can not from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication.

This code can run.

```
import PySide2.QtWidgets as ps
import sys

def guiMain(args):
    app = ps.QApplication(args)
    window = ps.QWidget()

    address = ps.QLineEdit()
    button = ps.QPushButton("Go")
    layout = ps.QHBoxLayout(window)
    layout.addWidget(address)
    layout.addWidget(button)
    window.show()

    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    guiMain(sys.argv)
```

But this one is not.

```
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QHBoxLayout
import sys

def guiMain(args):
    app = QApplication(args)
    window = QWidget()

    address = QLineEdit()
    button = QPushButton("Go")
    layout = QHBoxLayout(window)
    layout.addWidget(address)
    layout.addWidget(button)
    window.show()

    return app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    guiMain(sys.argv)
```

[image]

No name 'QApplication' in module 'PySide2.QtWidgets'
....
No name 'QHBoxLayout' in module 'PySide2.QtWidgets']

I use VSC in window.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59955890/6622587 and change `PyQt5` to `PySide2`