# No name 'QApplication' in module 'PySide6.QtWidgets'

Tags: python, pyside6

I can't figure out how to use Pyside6 correctly.
I always get the same Error: `No name 'QApplication' in module 'PySide6.QtWidgets'`
As Extensions I use 'Python' and 'Qt for Python'.
I use vs-code, Python 3.11.2, windows.
Version of pyside:
shiboken6: 6.4.2
PySide6-Essentials: 6.4.2
PySide6-Addons: 6.4.2

I tried to uninstall/ install Pyside6 -addons/ -essentials/ -shiboken
and cleared the cache with 'pip cache purge' before reinstalling
As suggested from the warnings during the installation, I added the given Path to the environment variables.

Comment: What "given path"?

Comment: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts

Comment: The comment said something like: WARNIGS: Add 'The comment before' to Path to be able to use certain elements of Pyside. So I went to the environment variables and added it.

Comment: Given by whom? What comment? Also, if you're reporting error or warnings, don't be vague, *copy* the exact text, [edit] the post, add that and explain yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The OP doesn't mention where these errors are actually seen. However, at least in VS Code one may get similar errors from pylint in the code editor view.

For PySide6 and VS Code, I was able to fix this by adding a **.pylintrc** file into the project root with the following content:

```
extension-pkg-whitelist=PySide6
```

Restart VS Code and/or its code editor Windows if it doesn't seem to take effect right away.

For more details, see this old question and its answers: [No name 'QApplication' in module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' error in Pylint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56726580/no-name-qapplication-in-module-pyqt5-qtwidgets-error-in-pylint)